# How to create reusable Python component

Tags: python

This follows from Garrett's fantastic answer here: [In Python, given x-value on 2D Bezier Curve, return y-value](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8465/in-python-given-x-value-on-2d-bezier-curve-return-y-value)

(EDIT: question generalised as per suggestion)

Say we have a Python file Foo.py containing the function X(p,q)

I would like to set things up so that my scripts can call X(...), rather than have to copy-paste its definition into each script that wants to invoke it.

How to accomplish this? And where is the right place to put Foo.py?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about python module / package organization and nothing blender-specific.

Comment: this question would be better suited for stack overflow

Comment: This question seems on-topic because it requires a Blender-specific answer (see my and Pi's answers).

Comment: Glad to hear you liked that function I wrote!  But perhaps you could streamline the question, so make it more generic and get rid of the references to getYfromXforBezierObject, NumPy, etc.  You could just call the function foo().  It just seems like there's some extraneous details...

Comment: Sorry all, I have rewritten the question. I think that the question of "where to put the file" does have some specific 'Blender' relevance. (I can see that "How to access a function from another file" OTOH is a pure Python question")

Answer (score 3):

You could save the file into the `site-packages` directory, which is found by going to your Blender folder and then `2.70` > `python` > `lib` > `python3.3` > `site-packages`.

Say your file is called "Foo.py" and has in it a function

```
def X(p,q):
    return p + q
```

then, after saving it into `site-packages`, in the Blender text editor or console, you could use:

```
from Foo import X
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I need to do.

I have my own ~/Dev/BlenderScripts folder (as per http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout)

I set *File > User Prefs > Scripts* to "/users/pi/Dev/BlenderScripts"

(Note: using ~ does seem to work but it doesn't show up on sys.path; I have filed a potential bug: https://developer.blender.org/T39680?workflow=create)

Then with the mouse over the 3-D view, I press <kbd>F8</kbd>, which reloads Python stuff.

Then I check in Blender's Python prompt by doing:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

And it will show up **/users/pi/Dev/BlenderScripts/**{ **addons**, **modules**, **startup** }

I then create **modules/Foo.py**, which contains function:

```
def X(p,q):
    print( (p,q) )
```

Then from another script, or from Blender's Python prompt, I do:

```
from Foo import X
X(1,2)
```

Comment: It appears that inside your scripts directory, there must be at least one of the directories: `addons`, `modules` or `startup`.  And you must put the file into one of these.  I know this is what you did, but could you make it more explicit (that part tripped me up)?

Answer (score 1):

You have a full article on the blender wiki wich is going to help you:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Multi-File_packages

I've nothing to explain all is in the wiki.